# Applying a function twice with different text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a mock chat bot, and noticed that when I want my bot to reply in 2 lines, for instance:

> Hi I'm bot.

and

> who are you?

I either get 1 of these outcomes.

**Outcome 1:**
The JS only pushes the last `send` function

**Outcome 2:** JS pushes them both at the same time, but the animation is no longer there.

Here is my Send function I am working on:

```
function send_msg(msg) {
  var prevState = $("#conversation").html();
  if (prevState.length > 3) {
    prevState = prevState + "<br />";
  }

  //Add bot name before each message
  $("#conversation").html(
    prevState +
      "<span class='current_msg'>" +
      "<span class='bot'>Chatbot: </span>" +
      msg +
      "</span>"
  );
  $(".current_msg").hide();
  $(".current_msg").delay(1200).fadeIn();
  $(".current_msg").removeClass("current_msg");
}
```

Then, for this part of the conversation, here is where I am trying to load two responses:

```
function ai(msg) {
  if (username.length < 3) {
    username = msg;
    send_msg("Hi " + username + ", nice to meet you!");
    // Remove text bar
    $('#controls').empty();
    send_msg("Have you ever heard about conversational ui?");
  }

  // function options
}
```

Here is my **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0k1Lhh0p/)** as well.

Any ideas on how I can get both `send_msg` commands to show, while keeping my fade-in effect?

Comment: Have a look at using `.appendTo` http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/  instead - this will return the new element so you don't need to reference it by class.  Add a `console.log` to send_msg to see exactly when it's being called/

Comment: is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/627j6sha/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use callbacks to achieve what you want. You execute each line after the previous one has finished. I've [updated your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0k1Lhh0p/1/)

Firstly you should be removing the class `current_msg` after the fade has finished and then you can pass a callback into `send_msg` as a second argument and execute that on completion of `send_msg`.

```
function send_msg(msg, callback) {
  var prevState = $("#conversation").html();
  if (prevState.length > 3) {
    prevState = prevState + "<br />";
  }

  //Add bot name before each message
  $("#conversation").html(
    prevState +
      "<span class='current_msg'>" +
      "<span class='bot'>Chatbot: </span>" +
      msg +
      "</span>"
  );
  $(".current_msg").hide();
  $(".current_msg").delay(1200).fadeIn(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("current_msg");
    if ( typeof callback == "function")
        callback();
  });
}
```

Then just nest your messages:

```
send_msg("Hi " + username + ", nice to meet you!", function () {
    send_msg("Have you ever heard about conversational ui?");
});
```

Comment: Awesome solution, I'll be needing to append new controls based on the question so this will help with that as well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$(".current_msg").removeClass("current_msg");` you're removing the element's class before `$(".current_msg").delay(1200).fadeIn();` is executed and the first message remains hidden. What you will need to do is to call `send_msg` after the previous message was shown. You can do that using something like this:

```
function ai(msg) {
  if (username.length < 3) {
    username = msg;
    $('#controls').empty();
    send_msg("Hi " + username + ", nice to meet you!", function(){ 
        $(".current_msg").removeClass("current_msg");
        send_msg("Have you ever heard about conversational ui?");
    });
  }
}

function send_msg(msg, callback) {
  ....
  $(".current_msg").hide();
  $(".current_msg").delay(1200).fadeIn(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to introduce two concept:

- Callback function: define a specific function at the end of an operation (after message is sended)
- Queue: call the callback

See following please:

```js
// Get User's name
var username = "";

function send_msg(msg, callback) {
  var prevState = $("#conversation").html();
  if (prevState.length > 3) {
    prevState = prevState + "<br />";
  }

  //Add bot name before each message
  $("#conversation").html(
    prevState +
      "<span class='current_msg'>" +
      "<span class='bot'>Chatbot: </span>" +
      msg +
      "</span>"
  );
  $(".current_msg").hide();
  $(".current_msg").delay(1200).fadeIn()
  .queue(
    () => {callback && callback()}
  );
  $(".current_msg").removeClass("current_msg");
}

function get_username() {
  send_msg("Hello, I'm Kyle, what's your name?");
}

function ai(msg) {
  if (username.length < 3) {
    // Remove text bar
    $('#controls').empty();
    
    username = msg;
    send_msg("Hi " + username + ", nice to meet you!", () => {
    send_msg("Have you ever heard about conversational ui?");
  });
  }

  // function options
}

$(function() {
  get_username();

  $("#message").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      if ($("#slideThree").prop("checked")) {
        $("#sendMsg").click();
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });

  $("#sendMsg").click(function() {
    // Set user's name in front of each message
    var userName = "<span class='username'> Me: </span>";
    var newMsg = $("#message").val();

    $("#message").val("");

    var prevState = $("#conversation").html();
    if (prevState.length > 3) {
      prevState = prevState + "<br />";
    }
    $("#conversation").html(prevState + userName + newMsg);

    ai(newMsg);

    $("#conversation").scrollTop($("#conversation").prop("scrollHeight"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
      <div class="contain">
        <!--h1>
          Chat
        </h1-->
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="contain" id="conversation"></div>
    <div class="contain" id="controls">
      <textarea id="message" placeholder="Type Your Message"></textarea><button id="sendMsg">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div class="contain">
      <div class="slideThree left">
        <input checked="true" id="slideThree" name="check" type="checkbox" value="none" /><label for="slideThree"></label>
      </div>
      <p class="left checkLabel">
        Send on Enter
      </p>
    </div>
```